# Springsourcetoolsuite sample project throwing maven dependency issues

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-batch

I am new to STS and installed the latest version yesterday. Once installed I went to New->Spring Template Project->Simple Spring Batch Project and followed the instructions like giving a project name, specifying a package name and clicked finish.

The project is showing a lot of errors. I tried updating maven dependencies and clicked almost all logical options in maven. I even see that org.springframework is not resolved. I see "Failed to read artificat descriptor errors".

Can anybody guide me here? Since this is a sample project I expected it to compile and run straight away. Am i missing something?

My STS version is 2.7.2 and maven is 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, some of the template projects are a bit out of date.  I'd recommend posting on the STS forum for a bit of help on getting them working.

http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?32-SpringSource-Tool-Suite